# Workflow for managing duplicate cases

Tags: civicase

We've found an issue where a member of staff has created a new case for an existing contact instead of adding an activity to an existing case (Training and documentation is being addressed)

But it leaves us with a list of multiple cases of the same type on several client records.

There's no way of merging cases, so the best workflow I can think would be to identify one case as the "main case" to keep and work through the other cases and move any activities onto the main-case record.

Anybody got any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a merge case feature. The clients need to be the same client on both cases so you may need to merge contacts or change the client first. The feature is a little blue link about 1/4 way down the manage case screen.

You may also want to look at https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/mergecaseandkeepid since, for unfortunate historical reasons, the case id changes when you do a merge.

[image]

Comment: D'oh!

There are none so blind as cannot see.

Must have skimmed over that hindreds of times.  Thank you!